# Adjunct Lecturer for 3 years applying for entry level software job. How do I convey leadership qualities?

Tags: software-industry, resume, software-development

Title says it all. I've been an adjunct lecturer for 3 years while completing my masters degree. I want to convey that I have leadership skills through this position. What's the best way to say it or write it that would immediately attract a recruiter? What leadership skills can a lecturer even write?

Comment: Well... what sort of leadership skills you feel are you strengths or that you specifically have?

Comment: What specific tasks where you involved with during that lecturer position? We can use those as a starting point to see which tasks and responsibilities you had involved leadership qualities.

Comment: How do you equate that with leadership skills?

Comment: TBH, entry-level jobs, regardless of what is written in the description, don't *actually* require "leadership skills". That's just HR job description boilerplate. Anyways, You have the advantage of a lot of experience educating students, evaluating them,  and keeping them on track. that's far FAR more than most of your competition and that is a form of leadership. Focus instead on how you can fit into their team.

Comment: University lecturers and professors have formal authority and students have a vested interest to listen to you. You usually have the benefit of knowing what's going to be tested because you wrote it. Engineering leadership is different. Since you're starting as an entry level software engineer, you'll need to know to lead without a title first and this is a difficult transition because it's likely you're used to a classroom of students listening to you.

Comment: @jcmack Classroom management is a skill in its own right.

Comment: How do you think would “leadership qualities” improve your chances to get a job with a company that requires an entry level software job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What leadership skills can a lecturer even write?

We don't know yet the specifics of the course(s) that you lectured, but regardless of that, **imparting a lecture involves having to lead the students/listeners in their learning process.** Besides preparing the lecture content and visual aids for the class, a lecturer/teacher should have the ability to be able to smoothly guide and present that content to their students.

We could say that we can make an analogy of this and compare it to a Team Lead: comprehending and translating the needs of the project/product (the course content), as given by the Stakeholders(the Directors and other faculty members), and conveying it to the team members (the students) in a way that they can understand, while coordinating and making sure they are able to carry on with their tasks (homework, examples, etc.).

That would be my take on making an analogy on imparting a lecture and being a Team lead (a stretch? perhaps a bit... but recall that this was an analogy).

Now, as only you know the specifics of the role you fulfilled as lecturer, I suggest you **make a list of the responsibilities and tasks you had while on that position. Then, select those that clearly involved leading people or that show leadership qualities** (for example, helping students with doubts on their course project). Finally, you can then use those tasks and list/explain them on your resume, so that your phrasing helps to convey the leadership qualities involved.

Comment: Writing down the responsibilities analogous to the Team Lead or similar will be important. I wouldn't call yourself a Team Lead (or de facto Team Lead) since that's really a big stretch.

Comment: @jcmack If the OP was in charge of delivering the unit/course/class/whatever, it wouldn’t be, because they’d likely be managing a team of academic staff to do so.

Answer (score -1):

## Include a mention of any tutors/TAs that you managed.

Generally, a university lecturer doesn’t teach a course/unit/class/[whatever jargon term your university uses] by themselves. They lead a team of other staff (often referred to as something like “tutors” or “teaching assistants”), who assist them by teaching smaller tutorials and practical classes, along with assisting in the marking process - and for the latter part, they’d need to manage their work to make sure that all the tutors/TAs are marking papers to the same standard.

This might be a bullet point under the listing of the job on your resume of something like “managed a team of X academic staff to deliver course content to students and assess their learning”.

Additionally, tenure-track faculty usually manage a team of researchers and PhD students doing research, but since you mentioned that you were doing a Master’s degree, you obviously weren’t doing any of that.

Comment: "Generally"...I think you should disclose the countries this answer is about.